# Maven - hangs on building a project

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven to build projects that may or may not have children (not sure if that is related).  I have many projects before this one that build fine, but this one just sits there.  It doesn't have anything special in the pom.xml, but it just hangs during the compile phase.

Any ideas what I can do?  Is there a limit on the number of children a project can have?

Stack Trace from running kill -3 PID:

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode):

"resolver-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a5473f800 nid=0x4a5a waiting on condition [0x00007f2a5b61a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e08c45f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a54922800 nid=0x4920 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2a5b216000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e2255160> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000e2255160> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$ReferenceQueueThread.run(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1122)

"resolver-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a54a4f000 nid=0x488d waiting on condition [0x00007f2a5b519000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e08c45f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"resolver-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a54a24000 nid=0x488c waiting on condition [0x00007f2a5b317000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e08c45f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"resolver-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a54a48800 nid=0x488b waiting on condition [0x00007f2a5bb8c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e08c45f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"resolver-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a54a45000 nid=0x488a waiting on condition [0x00007f2a5b857000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e08c45f0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Keep-Alive-SocketCleaner" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a548d9000 nid=0x4833 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2a5b115000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0d43928> (a sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStreamCleaner)
    at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStreamCleaner.run(KeepAliveStreamCleaner.java:101)
    - locked <0x00000000e0d43928> (a sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStreamCleaner)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2a5c177800 nid=0x4505 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2a6010b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e03c1470> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000e03c1470> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer.run(Finalizer.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d23800 nid=0x44e8 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d20800 nid=0x44e7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d1d800 nid=0x44e6 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d1b000 nid=0x44e5 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001cbe800 nid=0x44e4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2a61be6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0281070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000000e0281070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000001cbc800 nid=0x44e3 in Object.wait() [0x00007f2a61ce7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000e0280de8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000000e0280de8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001c21000 nid=0x44df runnable [0x00007f2a68357000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.WeakHashMap.get(WeakHashMap.java:376)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$MembersClosureCache.visitClassType(Types.java:2129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$MembersClosureCache.visitClassType(Types.java:2101)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$ClassType.accept(Type.java:583)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$DefaultTypeVisitor.visit(Types.java:3712)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.membersClosure(Types.java:2154)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types$ImplementationCache.get(Types.java:2064)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.implementation(Types.java:2096)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.implementation(Symbol.java:1226)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$MethodSymbol.implementation(Symbol.java:1215)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkCompatibleConcretes(Check.java:1538)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkCompatibleSupertypes(Check.java:2071)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:3204)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3154)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:3090)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:3064)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1182)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:870)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:829)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:417)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:331)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:322)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:554)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001cb4000 nid=0x44e2 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001c2c000 nid=0x44e0 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001c2d800 nid=0x44e1 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000001d2e000 nid=0x44e9 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 349

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 135936K, used 93082K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 113280K, 62% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f9a2e6a8,0x00000000fc400000)
  from space 22656K, 99% used [0x00000000fe9e0000,0x00000000ffff83b8,0x0000000100000000)
  to   space 30720K, 0% used [0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fc400000,0x00000000fe200000)
 PSOldGen        total 241408K, used 185439K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000eebc0000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 241408K, 76% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000eb517f78,0x00000000eebc0000)
 PSPermGen       total 168832K, used 168769K [0x00000000d5a00000, 0x00000000dfee0000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 168832K, 99% used [0x00000000d5a00000,0x00000000dfed0678,0x00000000dfee0000)
```

Comment: No idea. You will need to dump some extra information. I don't think there is a limit for number of modules for a project.

Comment: Does running with "mvn -X -e compile" reveal anything interesting?  Perhaps post the logs somewhere.

Comment: Is it hanging with a busy CPU, or idle?

Comment: nope, it just sits there when it starts to compile

Comment: Get the (maven/javacc) process PID and execute 'kill -3 PID' and see where it hangs, post the stack trace. Are you sure is in the compile phase? run maven with -X option to get more information...

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with similar kill -3 output caused by COMODO Anti-Virus for Linux. Removing that software eliminated the problem.